# Handle push notifications via UIAlertview

Tags: ios, iphone

Receiving push notifications and trying to handle through alert view and on selection of a button of alert view want to navigate to a particular view controller.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
    NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App"
                                                        message:@"You got a new request."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                              otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
    [alertView show];

} else {
    //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active
}
}
```

I want to move on the click of show button to another view controller.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{

}
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
    [self showNewContact];
}
}

-(void)showNewContact
{

Edit_app_viewController *detail=[[Edit_app_viewController alloc]init];

UIViewController *c = [self topViewController];
NSLog(@"View iS %@",c);

[c.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

}
```

Receiving error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x169f5f10'
*** First throw call stack:

Please guide.

Update:

```
 - (UIViewController*)topViewController
{
return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}
```

Comment: Please show whats in `[self showNewContact];` may be the problem lies there.

Comment: are you sure that `topViewController` has a `navigationController` ??

Comment: @MahmoudAdam It is clear that top view controller is UIModalItemsPresentingViewController not navigationController

Comment: Show your `topViewController` method too

Comment: @arturdev please check now.

Comment: I want to know how you calculated the top view controller. So show the source of that root method that calculates your top view controller.

Comment: @arturdev Please tell if you have any solution to it, tell your own way i will try that leave this top view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to calculate your top view controller.

```
+ (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController
{
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: what view to pass in rootViewController?

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController`

Comment: Had this method already, tried earlier also and now with your way also it navigates to  that view but crashes there when press back. it says [Edit_app_viewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x181dfa00

Comment: Hold your `Edit_app_viewController *detail` with `strong` pointer and then push it

Answer (score 0):

I think since UIAlertView is now a UIAlertViewController since iOS8 , may be the problem is that you need to wait till the alert is dismissed and than push a new controller you can do  like

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{

}
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(showNewContact) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
}
```

This way first alert will be dismissed and than new VC will be pushed.

Comment: No giving crash again

Comment: And it is giving crash in ios7 and 8 both

Comment: I think @artudev's answer should help you , Problem must be now that you are not able to find correct VC

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are pushing a `ViewController` while you don't have a `NavigationContoller`

you should put your modal view that is presented into a `UINavigationController`

update:

the problem is that you need to grantee that the rootViewController is always a UINavigationController as you can get the push notification any time while using the app, so i suggest to enclose your rootViewController into a UINavigationController

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController]; 
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Comment: the problem is that you need to grantee that the `rootViewController` is always a `UINavigationController` as you can get the push notification any time while using the app, so i suggest to enclose your `rootViewController` into a `UINavigationController`, i.e. `UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;`